# How to (globally) adjust space between two specific environments in LyX?

Tags: spacing, lyx

**(1) Between Parbox and Standard**

I want to add a space wherever Parbox is immediately followed by Standard. However, I do not want to add a space between two Parboxes.

So in the example below, I want to add a space between lines

- 2 and 3;
- 5 and 6;
- 7 and 8.

However, I don't want to add a space between lines 4 and 5.

[image]

What can I add to the preamble to achieve this result?

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
1

\noindent\fbox{\parbox[t]{1\columnwidth - 2\fboxsep - 2\fboxrule}{%
2%
}}

3

\noindent\fbox{\parbox[t]{1\columnwidth - 2\fboxsep - 2\fboxrule}{%
4%
}}

\noindent\fbox{\parbox[t]{1\columnwidth - 2\fboxsep - 2\fboxrule}{%
5%
}}

6

\noindent\fbox{\parbox[t]{1\columnwidth - 2\fboxsep - 2\fboxrule}{%
7%
}}

8
\end{document}
```

**(2) Between two Exercises**

Similarly, I want to globally add a space between any two Exercises (but not between any other environment and Exercise or between Exercise and any other environment). What can I add to the preamble to achieve this result?